# Magento Layout reference not coming to left

Tags: magento

so please help me in this..I am just trying to move the default cart to left

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
            <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>  
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

I am making reference block as "left" but the cart is not coming on left side but it has been disappeared from right side.

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: i am putting in layout file checkout.xml

Comment: Add the full contents of the `<checkout_cart_index>` handle to your post please.

Answer (score 1):

Is the page using the 2columns-left layout? If it's not, you'll never see anything on the left sidebar. You can fix this with a layout update:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: left column exist in page because popular tag column is coming in left and its reference name is set to left.also when i am trying to set Popular tag reference as right it is also not visible